# Sliding List View Animation too fast first time - Android

Tags: android, listview, button, slider, view

I have implemented an Animation in java  for the listview , It's like when you click a list item a view slides down with two buttons performing separate options on click, and on clicking once more it slides upward making the list item look normal (it does push other items up and down too) so the duration has been set to 500 for this animation so that it goes smooth.

But, The problem is that the first click on a list item displays the animation too fast (after the first click its all smooth again)
this is same for all the list items.

I tried a lot to solve this . I'll let you have a look at my animation class and my onitemclicklistener .

(PROBLEM 2 :- 1st ONE IS MORE IMP BUT IF YOU CAN SOLVE THIS TOO THEN GO AHEAD)
There's one more problem , sorry but forget the animation for a second , when the view slides down and you scroll down as much that you cant see the list item, now when you come back up the list item is'nt expanded anymore (slide out) , this is because of recycling of views , but how can i get around this too

ANIMATION CLASS :-

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public ExpandCollapseAnimation(View view, int type) {

    setDuration(500);



    mAnimatedView = view;
    mEndHeight = mAnimatedView.getMeasuredHeight();
    mLayoutParams = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams());
    mType = type;
    if(mType == EXPAND) {
        setDuration(500);

        mLayoutParams.bottomMargin = -mEndHeight;
    } else {

        setDuration(500);

        mLayoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
    }
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    setDuration(500);

    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
    if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
        if(mType == EXPAND) {
            setDuration(500);
            mLayoutParams.bottomMargin =  -mEndHeight + (int) (mEndHeight * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            setDuration(500);
            mLayoutParams.bottomMargin = - (int) (mEndHeight * interpolatedTime);
        }
        Log.d("ExpandCollapseAnimation", "anim height " + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin);

        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
    } else {
        if(mType == EXPAND) {
            setDuration(500);
            mLayoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
        } else {
            setDuration(500);
            mLayoutParams.bottomMargin = -mEndHeight;
            mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

}

IMPLEMENTATION :-

```
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                View toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                if(toolbar.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                    ExpandCollapseAnimation expandAni = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(toolbar, 0);
                    toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni);
                }else if(toolbar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    ExpandCollapseAnimation expandAmi = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(toolbar, 1);
                    toolbar.startAnimation(expandAmi);
                }



            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved , Just Had to use the ExpandableSlidingListview library but i feel it uses a lot of ram so this question is still open. :D